# What is "-[UIApplication beginIgnoringInteractionEvents] overflow. Ignoring."?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

After adding about 25 animation blocks within a for loop, there are a lot of `-[UIApplication beginIgnoringInteractionEvents] overflow. Ignoring.` messages showing in the Xcode debug window.

What does the message mean? Can I safely ignore them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697029/ignoring-ui-events-in-appkit).  Probably what's happening is that under the hood, your animation blocks are blocking the UI with this call.  However, the UI is already blocking due to a previous animation -- probably the system is letting you know that you can't nest any deeper.

As long as the UI comes back to life when the animations are done, I'd say it's probably not an issue?

Comment: appear even in iOS 8. One example to reproduce the message is: changing view controller when video is playing.