# How to match beginIgnoringInteractionEvents before adding endIgnoringInteractionEvents

Tags: ios

I am using these two functions `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];` and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];` while I am downloading data from server.

I am getting below error in my log.

```
-[UIApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents] called without matching -beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. Ignoring.
```

I tried to search on few links but can't find appropriate solution for this.

[How do you disable touch to screen without using beginIgnoringInteractionEvents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379842/how-do-you-disable-touch-to-screen-without-using-beginignoringinteractionevents)

[What is “-[UIApplication beginIgnoringInteractionEvents] overflow. Ignoring.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784971/what-is-uiapplication-beginignoringinteractionevents-overflow-ignoring)

[Ignoring UI Events in AppKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697029/ignoring-ui-events-in-appkit)

[beginIgnoringInteractionEvents or userInteractionEnabled = NO not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707633/beginignoringinteractionevents-or-userinteractionenabled-no-not-working-as-exp)

Comment: It is not even an error. `-[UIApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents] called without matching -beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. Ignoring.` See the `Ignoring`? (Haha). UIKit doesn't care about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always check.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isIgnoringInteractionEvents])...
```

Comment: @Rok:  isIgnoringInteractionEvents is returning true even if I haven't called beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. This happens after an alert view is closed. Any idea what may be happening?

Comment: Hmm, never had faced this issue. So you get false to isIgnoring... and true after is is closed? Is that correct? Do you have full control over this alert (part of your code) or is it part of 3rd party code?