# Getting endIgnoringInteractionEvents message in console

Tags: iphone, ios6

My app gets endIgnoringInteractionEvents message in console. But sometimes get crashed after this message if use breakpoints. Below is the message.

```
[UIApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents] called without matching -beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. Ignoring.
```

I studied on it and found that it is used before and after animation to handle the user interaction during animation. But i have not used these events in my project, so how come it is giving this error i am not getting. ALl this thing happens when using paypal sdk. Just after i complete the payment process in paypal and paypal library exits after that this occurs. How to handle this please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can always check

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isIgnoringInteractionEvents])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}
```

Comment: oh. I see. You are not using this function anywhere. See the reference links provided in this question. Might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061917/how-to-match-beginignoringinteractionevents-before-adding-endignoringinteraction